# Django view sending empty reply with proper headers

Tags: python, django, apache, mongodb, django-nonrel

I have Django project on Dreamhost server which has several views that returns Json response.Yesterday I have ported my Django project from local machine(localhost) to dreamhost server running apache.Now if I call my django view through jquery for

`http://www.abc.com/projects/`

It should return me all projects that i have in my mongodb database but instead of that it returns :

**On Firefox** - just headers with no response

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Thu, 19 Jan 2012 09:03:34 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=2, max=100
Server  Apache
Status  200 OK
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

**On Chrome** - No headers and response data.It throws an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.com/Projects/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**
```

If I just access the **http://www.abc.com/projects/** through my web-browser it returns me results in json format,but not in case if I use JavaScript/Jquery.

Earlier I was using this [middleware](https://gist.github.com/426829) to allow other domains to request and get response on my local-machine with django in-built server.But now when I am running on apache server It stops working so I removed It from Settings.py file.

I don't know why is this error coming .Please help

****EDIT****

As @burhan suggested I used jsonp on client side and now my server is  returning  json but browser is giving error before parsing it.Error is : unexpected token

JSON i am getting in reply is :

```
{"projects": [{"projectName": "carmella", "projectId": "4f13c7475fcff30710000000"}, {"projectName": "SeaMonkey", "projectId": "4f1677b75fcff37c03000001"}]}
```

Comment: You need to create another question with your JSON error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) sandbox. Since your server is **www.abc.com** and you are accessing **abc.com** - the origin is not the same, which is why the script is not executing.

You have a few options:

1. Make sure the URL matches exactly - to avoid the same origin policy sandbox.
2. Use [jsonp](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29) in your javascript libary.